# Nativescript - android Intent code not working

Tags: nativescript

I've got an {N} app with an Android specific call.

intent.putExtra( "variable", 123 );

It looks like {N} is using the putExtra(String,double) overload.

How can I force it to the putExtra(String,int) overload.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.lang.Integer` from native code for this

```
intent.putExtra( "variable", new java.lang.Integer(123) );
```

Comment: Actually after reading the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/js-to-java), {N} interprets a number as an int by default. The problem was something else - but I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I had problem with this in chart plugin so i used java.lang.Integer to force int too :)